# Remove white spaces on SQL Server for char datatype

Tags: php, sql, string

I have a field that has datatype `char(2)` 
the record value is A, B, AB, and O 
when i print AB to the php, it goes no problem, but if i print the others, it's printed with whitespace from sql like `"A "` << with whitespace

Comment: Change the definition of the field to `varchar(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in MSSQL, then use [RTRIM()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) and [LTRIM()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx)

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(columnname)) from tablename
```